# Mxchip IOT dev kit receiving data from IOT hub

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, mxchip

I just started playing with the mxchip. I want my device to trigger an alarm when receiving some command. It seems to me all examples I found are device collecting info and send to iot hub. Can mxchip receive data from iothub or azure function? And maybe some guidance on getting started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, assuming you use the SDK from the examples for the MXChip you have those handlers available:

```
DevKitMQTTClient_SetMessageCallback(MessageCallback);
DevKitMQTTClient_SetDeviceMethodCallback(DeviceMethodCallback);
```

Examples:

```
static void MessageCallback(const char *payLoad, int size)
{
   Screen.print(1, payLoad, true);
}

static int DeviceMethodCallback(const char *methodName, const unsigned char *payload, 
   int size, unsigned char **response, int *response_size)
{
   LogInfo("Try to invoke method %s", methodName);
   // Do your logic...
   int result = 200;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its possible to send messages to device ( Cloud-to-device) from IOT Hub.
Here is some example mentioned in these links

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging